# Magento 2: Properly access an external js variable in the checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.3, javascript, frontend

**Pure HTML Example**

I'm trying to do **something as simple as the following html code**:

```
<button onclick="MyExtVar.run();">Run</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.MyExtApiKey = "test";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://my.external.script.url.js"></script>
```

Just to explain, the `MyExtVar` is generated by the external script url which uses the `window.MyExtApiKey` variable. When you click the button, it runs. Simple as that.

**Magento 2 simple test**

Just for testing purpose, I know **this is not the right way of dealing with JS**, I just want to test so I've added a block via a module in `view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="myextjs.init" template="DigitalPianism_MyExtJs::init.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And then, in my `view/frontend/templates/init.phtml` I use the **exact same code as the HTML example** :

```
<button onclick="MyExtVar.run();">Run</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.MyExtApiKey = "test";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://my.external.script.url.js"></script>
```

**BUT**, when I click the button I get a `MyExtVar is not defined` error.

Note that **the external JS is properly loaded**, I can see it from the Network tab in the console.

So two questions:

- First, **why is that behaving differently** that the pure HTML example?
- Second, **how can I fix that** ?

Comment: I don't think that the external library is properly loaded. Did you try to open your dev toolbar console and check if the MyExtVar variable?

Comment: @ToanTam yes I did, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I ended up digging in the external js code and here's what I've found.

Basically, the `MyExtVar` is defined this way:

```
! function(root, factory) {
    if ("object" == typeof exports && "object" == typeof module) {
        module.exports = factory()
    } else {
        if ("function" == typeof define && define.amd) {
            define("MyExtVar", [], factory);
        } else {
            if ("object" == typeof exports) {
                exports.MyExtVar = factory();
            } else {
                root.MyExtVar = factory();
            }
        }
    }
}(window, (function() { return { /* the code of the js here */ };}));
```

In pure HTML mode, the loop defines properly `MyExtVar` this way:

```
root.MyExtVar = factory();
```

However, in Magento 2, it enters this piece of code:

```
define("MyExtVar", [], factory);
```

And for some reason, it does not work, but that's another question, at least I've found the root cause of the problem.

So in order to access `MyExtVar`, I need to run the following code:

```
require(['MyExtVar'], function(myExtVar) {
    myExtVar.run();
});
```